# Batch file to delete Firefox cache for user profiles on terminal server

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-io

I would like to run a batch file that deletes the firefox cache folder for all user profiles on a terminal server. Much like ICSweep deletes temp internet files for all users.

```
Location: C:\users\ *username*\appdata\local\mozilla\firefox\profiles\ *random*.default\cache
```

The issues are the different username folders, and the name of the subfolder under firefox\profiles contains "*random characters*.default" and is different for all users.

Can this be done with a batch file? Or do I need something like a vb script ?

If this could be done, I would also do this for the Google Chrome cache

```
C:\users\ *username*\appdata\local\google\chrome\user data\default\cache
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done.  It just requires some simple batch recursion.  This script is fully ready to use. Just replace the `echo` commands with `del` commands when ready to delete the cache folders.

```
:: Hide Commands
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

:: Parse the Local AppData sub path
call :Expand xAppData "%%LocalAppData:%UserProfile%=%%"

set "xFirefox=\mozilla\firefox\profiles"
set "xChrome=\google\chrome\user data"

:: Start at the User directory
pushd "%UserProfile%\.."

:: Loop through the Users
for /D %%D in (*) do if exist "%%~fD%xAppData%" (
    rem Check for Firefox
    if exist "%%~fD%xAppData%%xFirefox%" (
        pushd "%%~fD%xAppData%%xFirefox%"

        rem Loop through the Profiles
        for /D %%P in (*) do (
            if exist "%%~fP\cache" echo "%%~fP\cache"
        )
        popd
    )

    rem Check for Chrome
    if exist "%%~fD%xAppData%%xChrome%" (
        pushd "%%~fD%xAppData%%xChrome%"

        rem Loop through the Profiles
        for /D %%P in (*) do (
            if exist "%%~fP\cache" echo "%%~fP\cache"
        )
        popd
    )
)
popd
goto End


::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:Expand <Variable> <Value>
if not "%~1"=="" set "%~1=%~2"
goto :eof


:End
endlocal
pause
```

---

**Update for Comment**

To use the Firefox profiles.ini file replace the check for firefox section above with this.

```
rem Check for Firefox INI
if exist "%%~fD%xAppData%%xFirefox%\profiles.ini" (
    pushd "%%~fD%xAppData%%xFirefox%\"

    rem Loop through the Profiles
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%L in (profiles.ini) do (
        if /i "%%~L"=="Path" if exist "%%~fM\cache\" echo "%%~fM\cache"
    )
    popd
)
```

Comment: you did not consider `isRelative=0` in `%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini`...

Comment: @anishsane Because the OP only mentioned the firefox\profiles folder. However, I have added the modification necessary to use the profiles.ini file.

Comment: just beware that it's probably not a very good idea to delete cache for currently logged on users running FireFox, so for that I suggest using quser command to see who is logged on, but I am not sure if it is possible with CMD to search for strings and such, so it would be better to use VBS or AutoIt. Also it is possible that some usernames are different then their profilefolder names...

Answer (score 0):

Updated version of the script above, only Firefox :

```
:: Hide Commands
rem @echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

:: Parse the Local AppData sub path
call :Expand xAppData "%%LocalAppData:%UserProfile%=%%"

set "xFirefox=\mozilla\firefox\profiles"
set "xChrome=\google\chrome\user data"

:: Start at the User directory
pushd "%UserProfile%\.."

:: Loop through the Users
for /D %%D in (*) do if exist "%%~fD%xAppData%" (
    rem Check for Firefox
    rem if exist "%%~fD%xAppData%%xFirefox%" (
    if exist  "%%~fD%xAppData%%xLocal%%xMozilla%%xFirefox%" (
        rem pushd "%%~fD%xAppData%%xFirefox%"
        pushd "%%~fD%xAppData%%xLocal%%xMozilla%%xFirefox%"

        rem Loop through the Profiles
        for /D %%P in (*) do (
            if exist "%%~fP\cache2" del /F /Q /S "%%~fP\cache2"
        )
        popd
    )
)
popd
goto End


::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:Expand <Variable> <Value>
if not "%~1"=="" set "%~1=%~2"
goto :eof


:End
endlocal
pause
```